# Crop Bitmap using RectF parameters on Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, zooming, crop

Using MikeOrtiz's [awesome ImageView implementation](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView) with touch and zoom events, I wanted to crop a picture taken with the camera to match the zoom. Using his method...

```
// Return a Rect representing the zoomed image.
RectF getZoomedRect();
```

...I tried cropping the resulting picture bitmap to the zoom size like so:

```
RectF zoomCoordinates = mTouchImageView.getZoomedRect();

Bitmap croppedBitmapToOverview = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                AppResources.sCurrentImage,
                ((int) zoomCoordinates.left),
                ((int) zoomCoordinates.top),
                ((int) zoomCoordinates.width()),
                ((int) zoomCoordinates.height()));
```

However I get a "must be bigger than 0" error with this. While debugging I noticed ALL values were 0 due to casting to an Integer. The real values however go something like this:

```
//Log.d print for each of those fields without the int cast
Left 0.34047672
Top 0.20797288
Width 0.33333334
Height 0.3429547
```

So there's my problem, but I can't see how to fix this. I've never worked with bitmaps before or canvas, Rect, etc.

Is there some tweaking I could do to these values, or should I take a different approach altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got around the problem by simply taking a "screenshot" of the View of sorts. This got me a Bitmap with the picture as it was zoomed

```
mTouchImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        AppResources.sCurrentImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(mTouchImageView.getDrawingCache());
```

Answer (score 0):

multiply the coordinates with the size of your image like

```
(int)(zoomCoordinates.left * imageSize)
```